How can I implement a 2x camera view as surface view?
I'm trying to make the surface view of my app, (android app), a live camera view that will always be zoomed in by two. It has a GUI on top of that. I do not need to zoom in or out. I just need to display the camera preview at 2x as the surface view. I have a Graphical user interface as an overlay. The app currently works, but, I can't get it to display the zoomed in surface view without other zoom functionality.
I have tried adding a zoom funcion, but, I only need it to display at 2x, without any other functionality.

Your App needs to implement two components:

A Camera Preview in your App
Zoom Controls (so that you can implement your 2x logic)

The former of the two can be achieved by looking at the following resource:
Camera Preview
The latter can be achieved by implementing the cameraControl from CameraX in this example:
cameraControl
With these things you can implement your camera with 2x Zoom.
